# MySQL group by month not working

Tags: mysql

I think I'm doing something silly as this query is not giving me desired output:

My table is this:

```
id integer, 
current_date date
```

The entries in table are:

```
1, 2016-08-24
2, 2016-08-25
3, 2016-08-26
4, 2016-07-21
5, 2016-07-22
```

Query:

```
select MONTH(current_date),count(*) 
from test 
group by MONTH(current_date)
```

This query is returning me:

```
8, 5
```

I was expecting:

```
7, 2
8, 3
```

Comment: GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(my_column, '%Y-%m')

Comment: "SELECT MONTH( date ) , count( * ) FROM test GROUP BY MONTH(date )"

It's gives me same output as you want i am not changing in your query.

Comment: SELECT MONTH( current_date ) , count( * ) FROM test GROUP BY MONTH(current_date );  Is something wrong with MySQL setting?

Comment: "current_date" this is wrong friend actually this is keyword of mysql if you want to continue with "current_date" this name then you can write like this way `\`current_date\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current_date` is a MySQL [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) that returns today's date. To use it as a table column, you need to put it in backticks.

```
select MONTH(`current_date`), COUNT(*)
from test
GROUP BY MONTH(`current_date`)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d048a/4)

Or you could rename the column to something that doesn't conflict with a reserved word.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks **Krunal**, the problem was that **current_date** is a reserved word.